# 428 connection server connecting to itself

Tags: wordpress

i have a wordpress website at nepaljapan.com. I recently contacted the server regarding the website load and performance issue. What i got from them was the following response.

"There is 428 connections from IP 166.63.31.176 - which is your server's IP to your server/application. That means that the server tries to reach himself not on localhost but on external ip address which is not good and cause huge load."

When i tried to re consult them they told that it is a code level issue so they cannot help further.

I could not figure out what is causing the issue at the code level as it is a normal wordpress site.

It would be great help if anyone could push me in the right direction?

Comment: What access do you have to server? e.g. can you read the logs yourself to confirm once the issue is fixed?

Is this a shared host, or a virtual/dedicated server? Edit: Nevermind, the ptr record points to your domain; definitely not a shared host.

Comment: i have full access to server its a vps host

Comment: So your A record and your MX record both point to 166.63.31.176.  How often does the wordpress site try to send out email? (Do you have a newsletter running from it? Or would it just be admin alerts?)

Any chance you could post whatever logs they used to show the 428 connections to itself? It may show the port number.

Comment: no it does not send out email only admin alerts, they are using "netstat -plan|grep :80" command to show the logs as tcp 0 0 166.63.31.176:80 166.63.31.176:60603 TIME_WAIT -
tcp 0 0 166.63.31.176:80 166.63.31.176:60530 TIME_WAIT -

Comment: May be you can ask them for some more info: like which process/program initiating those connection. There are many command line tools availble there. For example: `lsof -i :80` will show associated process

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some more information to diagnose the problem. There are lots of command line tools available for further investigation. You can ask them for more information using, for example:

```
lsof -i | grep :80 *(as root)*
```

Which will show all the associated processes. Or

```
netstat -nlp | grep :80
```

It will also display some more helpful info. There are many other tools out there.
Obviously you need to find out which program or process is initiating those connection for further troubleshooting.